# Python convert date time not working

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to parse string into python datetime object and this is the code:

```
created = datetime.strptime(r.json()[x]["created_at"], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: time data '"Wed Jan 16 22:08:18 +0000 2013"' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'
```

It should be correct, obviously I am doing something wrong.  As a note, the r.json returns the text in unicode, but I tried it with a str() conversion as well.

The full program:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from simplejson import dumps

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name='
username = 'gtklondike'
count = '5'

url += username + "&count=" + count

r = requests.get(url)

x = 0
while x < count:
    print "<div id='tw-body'>" + r.json()[x]["text"] + "</div>"
    created = datetime.strptime(dumps(r.json()[x]["created_at"]), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y") 
    print "<div id='tw-date'>Date: " + r.json()[x]["created_at"] + "</div><br />\n" # TMP --> until I get datetime working... but at least it shows you the date
    x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like there's an extra set of quotes in your string - one ' denoting that it's a string, and one " inside the string.

Try:

```
created = datetime.strptime((r.json()[x]["created_at"]).strip('"'), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
```

`strip('"')` removes the `"`s from the string.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue!  @wrgrs solution worked, but actually it is from the dumps() being around it, created an extra set of quotes. (It was his solution that triggered my idea)

```
created = datetime.strptime(r.json()[x]["created_at"], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
```

works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the parse function provided by [Delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) for future dealings with strptime  e.g

```
>>> from delorean import parse
>>> parse("2011/01/01 00:00:00 -0700")
Delorean(datetime=2011-01-01 07:00:00+00:00, timezone=UTC)
```

It accepts a wide range of string input as well as take into account different timezones and provides easy mechanisms for shifting, to retrieve the required datetime object simple `.datetime` on the delorean object.